# Error Banning Myself From My Own Website

Tags: php

Anyways, so when I Add an IP on my database it adds the IP into my MySQL database, but there's something wrong, if I type in a random IP, it bans me from the website, and when I enter the MySQL database it doesn't show me what IP is banned, the field is empty, and the date and time is just 00-00-00 00:00 or something, and I really can't find the error..

I think that this is the code that is somehow messed up, but I'm not too sure since I'm new to PHP and I've got some few other codes that had some errors before.

```
    <?php
 // Check if user is banned
 function check_banned($ip) {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT ip FROM ip_ban WHERE ip='$ip'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) != 0) {
        die("This ip <b>$ip</b> has been banned from this website!");
    } else {
        return false;
    }
 }

// Add a user ip to the database
function add_ban($ip) {
    $datetime = strftime("&Y-%n-%d %H:%M:%S");
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ip_ban (ip, datetime) VALUES ('$ip', '$datetime')");
    if($query == true) {
        echo "The IP <b>$ip</b> has been banned!";
    } else {
        echo "There was something wrong!<br/>Error: ". mysql_error();   
    }
}

// Removes a user ip from the database
function remove_ban($ip) {
    $query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM ip_ban WHERE ip='$ip'");
    if($query == true) {
        echo "The IP <b>$ip</b> has been unbanned!";
    } else {
        echo "There was something wrong!<br/>Error: ". mysql_error();   
    }

} 

?>
```

Here's the Add IP to ban list code:

```
<?php
include "core/init.php";

echo "<h1>Welcome to the Administrator page!</h1>";
echo "<a href='index.php'>Home</a> | <a href='admin.php'>Admin</a> | <a href='add.php'>Add</a> | <a href='remove.php'>Remove</a> | <a href='all.php'>Banned IPs</a>";
echo "<hr/>";

if(isset($_POST['add_btn'])) {
    add_ban($_POST ['ip.txt']);
}
?>

<form action="add.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="ip.txt" />
    <input type="submit" name="add.btn" value="Add" />
</form>
```

Okay THANKS guys for all of the comments/help I appreciate it all! 
I just realized I wrote %n and not %m so I pretty much messed up a lot, though I've fixed it all now, thanks so much! :) Topic solved.

Comment: Show the code where these functions are called

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: Those functions must be called to do anything. Show us the code where you are using them.

Comment: I've edited my post ^ , did you mean that?

Comment: But the date time is still wrong, it shows me 00-00-00 00:00..
Is there something wrong?
Oh also thanks, it did fix it! :)

Comment: Sidenote: This is invalid `<input type="text" name="ip.txt" />` which needs to be `<input type="text" name="ip_txt" />` and change `add_ban($_POST ['ip.txt']);` to `add_ban($_POST ['ip_txt']);` --- If you're trying to save or pull from a `.txt` file, you will need extra codes for that. @user3413045

Answer (score 2):

```
$datetime = strftime("&Y-%n-%d %H:%M:%S");
                      ^---not a valid formatting char
```

Because of that `&`, you're generating a date that looks like

```
&Y-03-14 09:16:00
```

which when inserted into the db, will be declared invalid and you get your all-zeroes date.

Comment: Do you know how to change the code to a valid one?
Because I don't know how to solve it.. :/

Comment: Thanks for the link! The site actually helps out, though it didn't solve my error, any type of chance you know how to solve it? :/

Comment: Just use `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`

Comment: @Perry, I might be wrong, but I tried it and still shows me 0000-00-00 00:00.. :/

Comment: @user3413045 what is the type of your field?

Comment: @Perry it is date and date in my MySQL database, before that it was datetime datetime, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: use datetime for the type of the field and `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` that should be working.

Comment: Can you please write me the code, I somehow can't get on your level :/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
if(isset($_POST['add_btn'])) {
add_ban($_POST ['ip.txt']);
}
```

Do this:

```
if(isset($_POST['add_btn'])) {
add_ban($_POST ['ip_txt']);
}
```

It is important to note that PHP will automatically replace any dots in incoming variable names with underscores.

Comment: Note that OP needs to also change `<input type="text" name="ip.txt" />` to read as `<input type="text" name="ip_txt" />` in order for your answer to be valid.

Comment: @Fred-ii- No that is not true, it would be better to do that. But you php will change the dot to an underscore so it is not needed to change that. If you don't believe me just try it out your self :).

Comment: I'm just saying that it's best to have consistency in code; a perfect match as it were ;-) I'm not saying I don't believe you, but I myself am always consistent when it comes to matching POST variables.

Comment: *Furthermore*, if someone else were to "take over" a contract for instance and notices `['ip.txt']` he/she may think that the original coder wanted to save to file; *think about that* ;-) If PHP changes it to an underscore automatically (*as you said*), why instruct the OP to change it to that in the first place?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Because you can't use `$_POST['ip.txt']` to get the result so you will need to that that to `$_POST['ip_text']`. I agree with you on the fact that it is better to use `ip_text` in the name tag.